# Intel Driver wont install

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

So I have an Intel(R) 4600 graphics card. Recently, Premiere Pro notified me of the fact that the driver I have installed is no longer compatible with it.

(Driver info:

Date: 08/08/2020

Driver Version:  20. 19. 15. 5166)

So I contacted Adobe directly, and they supplied this download link (https://downloadmirror.intel.com/29971/a08/win64_15.40.47.5166.exe
) and told me that I could find the driver to fix my problem there. So I downloaded it and installed it. Everything went well, but when I restarted the PC, I was surprised to see that the driver info on the "device manager" was the same as before. Which means the driver was not updated successfully. I've tried everything with the adobe customer service until they just told me to contact intel directly (which I was unable to do because the telephone numbers they provided for my country were down and their live chat was also down).

I honestly don't know what to do, and I need my Adobe programs up and running soon because, as I know you all will understand, my job depends on them.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: While you wait for a solution, why don't you install a previous version of premiere? they are available through the creative cloud app

Comment: have you tried the automatic update through the intel website, here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81496/Intel-HD-Graphics-4600

Comment: I would be inclined to go back to Adobe. I have a bit different Intel chip but my driver is V26 and yours is V20. Adobe is asking you to install V15 which does not see appropriate. Intel keeps its drivers in the Microsoft Catalogue so Windows will install what is in the catalogue. I have been down that road before.

Comment: @1NN I could do that. Though I fear the plug-ins I have will not be available, and the projects I'm working on all are made on newer versions of the program.

Comment: @John Thank you for commenting. That's an interesting observation. I could go back to them, they will not be offering support till Monday though...

Comment: @1NN yes, but the same problem happens again.

Comment: In some rare cases, you need the driver provided by your OEM (=manufacturer of your PC). You might check on their website. Example: if you have a DELL pc, google for "Dell intel 4600 driver update"

Comment: @1NN thank you for your support! oh yes, that's possible, but my PC is custom built!

Comment: [This](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29971/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-) is the last driver Intel has released for your GPU.  Please note that there isn't any other version of the Intel driver that has been released.  Any Intel driver released that is newer than that driver does not actually support your device.  Your product has been discontinued and is no longer supported by Intel.  If you want help with the reason it wasn't able to install you have to provide logs.  **I understand you linked to that file.**

Comment: @Ramhound how can I access the logs?

Comment: It doesn't matter you already have the drivers Adobe suggested installed (20.19.15.5166) that came directly from the readme text document.  The installation likely failed because the driver was already installed.

Comment: intel initially dropped all support for HD 2 & 3000 series chips at the advent of Win10, with very limited additional support for the 4000 series. In the past year they seem to have revised that initial decision & you can still get newer drivers for the 4000s. Try https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30196/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?wapkw=4600 or click the 'Get Started' on the auto update section, top left. idk if this will fix your issue, nothing to test on.

Comment: Premiere Pro 13.1.5 (still available through creative cloud) should work on your hardware. Otherwise try v. 12 (download link is here: https://prodesigntools.com/adobe-cc-2018-direct-download-links.html) You can install it along with the most recent version, to check if everything works. Also, it's easy to downgrade your projects so they will open in the old version. See here: http://joshcluderay.com/downgrade-premiere-project-converter/

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered the problem.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck. Intel has ceased support for its iGPUs that are older than 6th-Generation. At this moment, only critical bug fixes and security patches will continue to be updated for the 4th- and 5th-Generation CPUs. The new driver requires a newer CPU than what I have just to even install at all. This means that the ONLY way to circumvent that compatibility report would be to completely disable the iGPU in the EFI (BIOS), which will prevent the Intel graphics driver from loading every time Windows boots up. I'll also lose the QuickSync hardware encoding and decoding feature.

(This answer was taken and edited from the Adobe forum: https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/system-compatibility-error-4600-driver-error/td-p/10517968).

Comment: I would be inclined to escalate with Adobe. I was just servicing my Lenovo commercial desktop computer. Intel Graphics 4600 Driver, Version 20 (same as you). That machine is just 4 years old and nowhere near death. Adobe needs to service a broad range of machines - not just new ones.

Comment: @John That's interesting! I didn't know you were going through the same thing! Please keep me updated, because so far, Adobe has made it clear that there is pretty much no way to fix this!

Comment: I have Adobe Products but not Premier. So I cannot test that one. My other Adobe products seem to be fine. I did run my driver updates as part of my service and nothing updated

Comment: @John Interestingly, my other adobe products are working fine too. (Except After Effects).